# derivative of integral over bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

**Question**: Let $S$ be an bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (the real numbers). What is $$ \frac{d}{dy}\int_{x\in S}e^{x-y} dx\quad?$$

We can assume that $x$ is constant with respect to changes in $y$.

**Background**: A similar term occurs when I compute the second partial derivative of a special log-likelihood function to check whether it is convex.

**What I tried so far**: If $S$ were an interval, I think the solution would be $$ \frac{d}{dy}\int_{\inf S}^{\sup S} e^{x-y}dx = e^{\sup S - y}  - e^{\inf S - y}$$ whereas if $S$ were unbounded, I think the solution should be $$ \frac{d}{dy}\int_{x\in S} e^{x-y} dx =e^{x-y}.$$ But I struggle with a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that is not an interval because, e.g., $S$ might contain uncountably many 'gaps' over which we should not integrate because they are not part of $S$.

Comment: $\int_{x\in S}e^{x-y} dx=e^{-y}C$ where $C=\int_{x\in S}e^{x} dx$ is a constant.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks for the comment. So I would get $d/dy \int_{x\in S} e^{x-y}=-C e^{-y}$. Is there any way to get rid of the integration over $S$ in $C$?

Comment: No. it depends on what $S$ is. For example, if $S=\{0\}$ then $C=0$ but if $S=[0,1]$ then it is positive.

Comment: Not every bounded set is admissible for integration.

The first question would be what integral you are using: Riemann or Lebesgue? If you use the Riemann integral, then your set $S$ has to be at least [Jordan measurable][1].

And if you use the Lebesgue integral, it has to be [Lebesgue measurable][2].

  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure
  [2]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure